# Java setBounds not working with JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, layout-manager

i am doing a small Gui in java.  i am using   setBounds  methods to set the position of buttons etc on my JFrame , but problem is that when i use it with JPanel    button is not visible  on JFrame , and without  JPanel its quite ok  ,, see  both the codes  and please help me as  i am beginner and facing these foolish  problems .

This one is working fine

```
  JFrame jframe = new JFrame("Working Fine");  
  jframe.setLayout(null);  
  JButton jbutton = new JButton("Position Test");  
  jbutton.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);  
  jframe.add(jbutton);  
  jframe.setSize(300,300);
  jframe.setVisible(true);
```

Same code when i add  Button to Jpanel  then it does not work so whats wrong  , please guide me

```
  JFrame jframe = new JFrame("causing problem ");
  jframe.setSize(300,300);
  JPanel p = new JPanel();
  jframe.setLayout(null);  
  JButton jbutton = new JButton("Position Test");  
  jbutton.setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100);
  jframe.add(p);
  p.add(jbutton);
  p.setVisible(true);
 //jframe.add(jbutton);  
  jframe.setVisible(true);
```

please help me in this small problem

Comment: `setLayout(null)`, `setBounds(0, 0, 100, 100)`, and `setSize(300,300)` are really bad practice.

Comment: You should never use a null layout.  Read this layout manager tutorial: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: i am learning  Java and have not been taught  LayoutManagers yet and our instructor asked us to use null untill we go through   LayoutManagers , so did not  use them .  can u please guide me whta's wrong here ?

Comment: *"our instructor asked us to use null untill we go through LayoutManagers"*  Your instructor should not be instructing anyone until they have gained 'minimum competence' in the subject.  Anyone that had, would not tell you to use `null` layouts.

Comment: if you know what you are doing, null layouts are perfectly fine, guys. i mean it's just the gui, and the standart layoutmanagers REALLY suck. go html if you want boxed layouts, but when using a programming language, might aswell understand how to code a gui. I mean look at how perfect a simple forms element looks and compare that to swing

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that when you use absolute positioning, the `JPanel` component has no default size so does not appear. To get it to appear you could do

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("No Problem");
JPanel panel = new JPanel() {
    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(300, 300);
    };
};
panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
JButton button = new JButton("Position Test");
panel.add(button);
frame.add(panel);
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);
```

From [Doing Without a Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/none.html)

> Although it is possible to do without a layout manager, you should use a layout manager if at all possible. A layout manager makes it easier to adjust to look-and-feel-dependent component appearances, to different font sizes, to a container's changing size, and to different locales.

The choice of layout manager will depend on how you wish to lay out the components.

See [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html).

Comment: i am student and have not learned it yet ,  ok please guide me which one i should use  as beginner , Your answer is accepted .. Thanks

Answer (score 10):

You must get rid of the JPanel's layout, in order to set absolute positions:

> p.setLayout(null);

Comment: I was trying to do a absolute layout with percentages, and it didn't work until I tried this. It solves the question why setBounds isn't working, instead of questioning it.