# Add JPanel to contentPane within actionListener

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, actionlistener

I'm trying to add a JPanel to my JFrame within an actionListener method, but it appears only after the second click on the button. This is a portion of my code where `panCours` is a `JPanel` and `ConstituerData` the targeted `JFrame`  :

```
addCours.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            panCours.setBounds(215, 2, 480, 400);
            panCours.setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Saisir les données concernant le cours"));
            ConstituerData.this.getContentPane().add(panCours);
        }
    });
```

I don't understand why it doesn't appear as soon as I click on the button. Any explanation and help about how to fix this ?

Comment: See if calling `pack` on the `JFrame` in the end of `actionPerformed` solves your problem.

Comment: This call solves the problem, but creates another one : it sets each of the dimensions of my `JFrame` to 0.

Comment: @HugoSousa - He's using a null layout by the looks of things, so that's not going to help much. Try calling repaint on your JFrame, or JPanel.

Comment: Exactly, I'm using a `null` layout. @RudiKershaw, it solves the problem.

Comment: @sk001 take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13633503/java-setbounds-not-working-with-jpanel

Comment: The question that comes to mind is, why are using a `null` layout?

Comment: After taking a look at certain layouts, I am not able to add my components to the right place. Although, using a `null` layout might not be recommended.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to add a call to `repaint();` (as well as probably `revalidate();`) to get the JPanel to show immediately. A basic example demonstrating your problem (and the solution) below;

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        final JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLayout(null);

        JButton button = new JButton("Test");                       
        button.setBounds(20, 30, 100, 40);
        button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JPanel panel = new JPanel();
                panel.setBackground(Color.red);
                panel.setBounds(215, 2, 480, 480);
                frame.add(panel);
                frame.revalidate(); // Repaint here!! Removing these calls
                frame.repaint(); // demonstrates the problem you are having.

            }
        }); 

        frame.add(button);
        frame.setSize(695, 482);
        frame.setVisible(true);              

    }
}
```

The above said, (as suggested by others) it's only right that I recommend against the use of a `null` layout in future. The swing layouts are a little awkward to begin with, but they will help you a great deal in the long run.

Comment: Please, don't suggest the people use `null` layouts...it's just propergating bad advice and introducing more problems

Comment: Thanks, @RudiKershaw. It's now correct if I have only one `JPanel` to add. But I want to switch between many `JPanel` according to the choice of a button. Using this solution, the `JPanel` shown is not the the one corresponding to the `JButton` clicked. How can I do ?

Comment: @MadProgrammer - Quite right, I will update my answer to suggest a layout. But generally, once someone is deap into a project they wont want to change. Suggesting the use of a layout manager will help them in the future greatly, but it doesn't help them right now.

Comment: @sk001 - Are you remembering to remove the previous `JPanel` when you switch them and calling `repaint()` afterwards? I am afraid a new answer for multiple panels might be out of the scope of the question. You might have to post up a new one with more of your code demonstrating the issue.

Comment: @RudiKershaw, I'll then make a new post which describes explicitly my problem.

Answer (score 2):

the answer can be found in the following snippet:
you need to `revalidate()` the contentPane, not repaint the frame. you can add any panel you want to the contentpane like this. if you declare contentPane as a private field you dont need your `getContentPane()` call. contentPane is global so it can be reffered to directly from anywhere within the class. 
be careful about `NullPointerExeptions` which can be thrown if you refer to it before initialising.

```
public class testframe extends JFrame {

private JPanel contentPane;

/**
 * Launch the application.
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                testframe frame = new testframe();
                frame.setVisible(true);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Create the frame.
 */
public testframe() {
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    contentPane = new JPanel();
    setContentPane(contentPane);

    JButton btnNewButton = new JButton("New button");
    btnNewButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            JPanel a = new JPanel();
            contentPane.add(a);
            contentPane.revalidate();
        }
    });
    contentPane.add(btnNewButton);  
}

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097366/java-swing-revalidate-vs-repaint - To be absolutely safe, perhaps revalidating and repainting is in order. But certinaly not *just* revalidating.